# in vim pressing shift e or $ doesn't go completely to the end of word

Tags: vim

i have wired situation when i try to go to the end of the word using vim
`enter code here`VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jun 24 2019 23:56:49)
for example when i press shift e or $ it goes to 1 char before the end of the word 
for example :
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your cursor is going to the last character of the word, which is the intended behavior of `$` and `E`.

If you want to be able to place your cursor after the last character on a non-existent end-of-line character, enable that behavior with

```
set virtualedit=onemore
```

You could also define a custom mapping or overwrite a default one to move the cursor one more forward with `l` as part of the motion, for example

```
nnoremap E El
```

Comment: can i achieve it without setting fags ?

Comment: No. If you want to insert a character after your cursor, press `a` instead of `i`.

Comment: yeah this is what im doing for years

Answer (score 0):

To enter insert mode at the end of a line use `A`. You can also press `$` and then `a` to enter insert mode after the next character.